# Mo Pub add doesnot load

Tags: android, mopub

I want to give an MoPub add(banner) in my app.
I specified all required permission.

In  manifest

```
      <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
```

in my activity

```
     mAdView = (MoPubView) findViewById(R.id.adview);
     mAdView.setAdUnitId("My pub id provide by MoPub"); // Enter your Ad Unit ID from www.mopub.com
    mAdView.loadAd();


    mAdView.setOnAdLoadedListener(new OnAdLoadedListener() {
        public void OnAdLoaded(MoPubView mpv) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                "Ad successfully loaded.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

The problem is it doesnt load the add. Beacuse the toast "Ad successfully loaded"  doesnot appear.  But the request is recieved at MoPub because when I see the statistics on MoPub(in My account) it shows number of request incerases but  number of impressions are 0.

i configured InMobi ad network for my app.
i am testing on emulator with android 2.2.

Answer (score -1):

I have started using MoPub and have been having similar problems.  Check InMobi and see if they are getting the ad requests.  When I used InMobi as backfill from MobFox, I got something awful like a 9% fill rate.  Maybe they just don't have ads...

On the other hand, I've been testing MoPub with MillenialMedia and Admob, and after a brief period where requests went through, I'm seeing zero requests from either ad network, despite MoPub reporting lots of requests.  I'm not sure what's blocking them.

If you're seeing that situation, my suggestion would be to try the InMobi SDK directly and see if it works then.  MoPub adds an extra layer of complication.